# Como Guardar archivo txt en un servidor remoto con autenticación de usuario y password?

Tags: java

```
        private static final String START_NAME_FILE = "nombre_del_archivo"; 
        private static final String FILE_EXTENSION  = ".txt";


         String fileName            = START_NAME_FILE +"_"+formatCalToday+ FILE_EXTENSION;
         String credentialsUserName = Nombre_usuario
         String credentialsPassword = Pass_usuario
         String pathShared          = ip/ruta/equipo/remoto
         //extraemos la ip
         String ip                  = pathShared.substring(2,(pathShared.substring(2)).indexOf("\\") + 2);

        //creating txt file
        File file = new File(pathShared+fileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        //escribiendo en el archivo, Writing the file           
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        PrintWriter salida2 = new PrintWriter(out);

        if ( file.canRead() ) {
            Debug.logInfo("Se inicia el proceso de grabacion", module);
        }


        String fileContent = "Aquí Escribiremos cualquier cosa";
        salida2.write(fileContent);
        salida2.println();


        salida2.flush();
        salida2.close();
        out.close();

        String successMessage = " se genero  el archivo \""+fileName+"\" en la siguiente ruta \""+pathShared+"\"";
```

Este es un ejemplo de como puedo generar el txt, no es el que estoy generando en mi app es solo una referencia. Lo que faltaría es la conexión al servidor remoto.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
para futuras preguntas y respuestas, le recomiendo revisar este [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio , la pregunta era otra en el momento , ya que estaba usando JCIFS , de todos modos gracias por editar , quizás algún usuario le sirva en su momento mi solución. Saludos cordiales

Comment: igualmente, saludos y todos estamos para aprender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para establecer conexión en equipos Windows. se debe implementar el siguiente código, junto con el cual se describe la situación completa.

---

**Resumen:**

El código que sigue a continuación usa la linea de comando de windows (CMD).

```
// commandConnect, lo que hace usando la linea de comando de windows 
// ingresa con la ip, el usuario y la contraseña del servidor que esta compartiendo
String commandConnect = "cmd /c net use \\\\" + ip + "\\ipc$ /user:" + credentialsUserName + " " + credentialsPassword;
```

Una vez autenticado hay que capturar errores posibles con try catch y ademas usar el método `waitFor()` de la clase `Process`-que es la clase que maneja los procesos que se utilizan con la linea de comando de windows-.

Lo que hace `waitFor()` es esperar que el comando utilizado termine su proceso, haciendo que ningún otro proceso funcione hasta que el comando que esta en proceso termine:

```
// He expects the process to finalize
try {
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandConnect);
       int exitCode = process.waitFor();
       if (exitCode != 0) {
           throw new IOException("Command exited with " + exitCode);
       }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.getMessage();
}
```

Entonces el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
         private static final String START_NAME_FILE = "nombre_del_archivo"; 
        private static final String FILE_EXTENSION  = ".txt";


         String fileName            = START_NAME_FILE +"_"+formatCalToday+ FILE_EXTENSION;
         String credentialsUserName = Nombre_usuario
         String credentialsPassword = Pass_usuario
         String pathShared          = ip/ruta/equipo/remoto
         //extraemos la ip
         String ip                  = pathShared.substring(2,(pathShared.substring(2)).indexOf("\\") + 2);


         //connecting shared network with auth
         String commandConnect = "cmd /c net use \\\\" + ip
                    + "\\ipc$ /user:" + credentialsUserName + " " + credentialsPassword;

         //He expects the process to finalize
         try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandConnect);
                int exitCode = process.waitFor();
                if (exitCode != 0) {
                    throw new IOException("Command exited with " + exitCode);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
            }

        //creating txt file
        File file = new File(pathShared+fileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        //escribiendo en el archivo, Writing the file           
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        PrintWriter salida2 = new PrintWriter(out);

        if ( file.canRead() ) {
            Debug.logInfo("Se inicia el proceso de grabacion", module);
        }
```

Al loguearse correctamente, se crea y escribe en el archivo .txt, se cierra la conexión y se capturan sus errores.

Se desconecta solo con la ip de la otra máquina.

```
String commandDisconnect = "cmd /c net use \\\\" + ip + "\\ipc$ /d";
// He expects the process to finalize
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandDisconnect);
    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    if (exitCode != 0) {
        throw new IOException("Command exited with " + exitCode);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.getMessage();
}
```

Entonces cuando ya creamos el archivo en el servidor remoto tenemos que cerrar la conexión de la siguiente manera.

```
        String fileContent = "Aquí Escribiremos cualquier cosa";
        salida2.write(fileContent);
        salida2.println();


        salida2.flush();
        salida2.close();
        out.close();

        String successMessage = " se genero  el archivo \""+fileName+"\" en la siguiente ruta \""+pathShared+"\"";


            //Disconnect Auth
            String commandDisconnect = "cmd /c net use \\\\" + ip
                    + "\\ipc$ /d";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandDisconnect);
            //He expects the process to finalize
            try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandDisconnect);
                int exitCode = process.waitFor();
                if (exitCode != 0) {
                    throw new IOException("Command exited with " + exitCode);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
            }
```

Una forma de saber si estoy logeado o no es abrir el CMD y escribir lo siguiente:

> net use

Este comando nos debería mostrar las conexiones remotas de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan en la foto sale que estoy desconectado del equipo remoto, pero si entro a la carpeta compartida ya no me pedirá credenciales.

La forma en que nos desconectamos del equipo remoto mediante el código es la misma que voy a indicar ahora mediante linea de comando:

> net use\ip_de_la_maquina_remota\IPC$ /delete

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y voilà nos dira que **"se ha eliminado"**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si introducimos nuevamente el comando **net use** no dirá que **"No hay entradas en la lista"** y si tratamos de entrar nuevamente al equipo remoto nos pedirá las credenciales como debe ser.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PD: tener en cuenta que si el servidor no pide credenciales, funcionara de igual manera.**

Aquí les dejo la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) de la clase `Process` para mayor entendimiento.