# Guardar plantilla word en servidor

Tags: java, jsp

Tengo un problema con mi aplicación. Tengo una funcionalidad que descarga una plantilla en word del servidor, y la abre con el word, pero sin descargarla físicamente en el pc. En teoría tendría que al darle a guardar, se guarde en una ruta pre-establecida en el servidor, pero al darle a guardar me pide un lugar donde guardarla y no la puedo guardar en el servidor. Antiguamente si que se podía hacer, pero al hacer varios cambios al resto de la aplicación ya no se puede. Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

La aplicacion es una pagina web con Java/JSP. Un saludo

PD: Igual este no el sitio adecuado, pero no sabia donde poner la pregunta.

```
public String getTemplatePath(DbCnt cnt, CTTemplate ctTemplate) throws ISPACException {
    String sName = "";


    try {
         int e = ctTemplate.getTemplate();
         Date dateTemplate = ctTemplate.getDate();

         String mimetype = ctTemplate.getMimetype();

         String ext = MimetypeMapping.getExtension(mimetype);

         sName = Integer.toString(e) + "." + ext;


         OrganizationUserInfo info = OrganizationUser.getOrganizationUserInfo();
         if(info != null) {
            String file = info.getOrganizationId();
            sName = file + "_" + sName;
         }

         File file1 = new File(this.mFileDirContext.getDocBase(), sName);

         if(file1.exists()) {

            FileResourceAttributes attributes = (FileResourceAttributes)this.mFileDirContext.getAttributes(sName);

            Date dateFile = attributes.getLastModifiedDate();


            if(dateTemplate.after(dateFile)) {

               this.bind(cnt, sName, e);


            }
         } else {
            this.bind(cnt, sName, e);

         }
    } catch (Exception arg11) {

     throw new ISPACException(arg11);
    }

    return this.mFileDirContext.getDocBase() + "/" + sName;
}
```

Basicamente lo que entiendo que hace aqui es que genera el documento, con los datos del documento sacados de la base de datos. Entonces se abre el word, pero fisicamente no esta guardado en el pc, es como si fuese un temporal, no la descarga fisicamente.

Comment: *Sin descargarla  físicamente el pc* - Descargarla es necesario, otra cosa es que se haga en un archivo temporal. Si se ejecuta Word, éste tiene que tener acceso a la plantilla. Para guardarla en el servidor habría que subirla de nuevo, no sé cómo lo tendríais antes pero no hay manera de que se guarde automáticamente en el servidor sin que el usuario la suba de algún modo

Comment: La idea es que cuando el usuario guarda el documento, se guarde en el servidor directamente, que no pida la ubicacion de guardado en local. Antes era asi, pero ha habido cambios en el proyecto, y no se sabe cuando dejo de funcionar...

Comment: ¿Puedes copiar el código que realiza la descarga?

Comment: Ya esta el metodo puesto en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de lograr que el archivo se guarde en el servidor que requieres es usando  La clase Process, revisa la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) de java.

La conexión al servidor es mediante la línea de comando de windows **(CMD)**.

```
 //conectando a un servidor remoto o servidor local 
 //esto sirve con o sin la autenticación del servidor de windows

 String commandConnect = "cmd /c net use \\\\" + ip
            + "\\ipc$ /user:" + credentialsUserName + " " + credentialsPassword;

 //espera que el proceso finalize
 try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandConnect);
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        if (exitCode != 0) {
            throw new IOException("Command exited with " + exitCode);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
```

Una vez autenticado deberías comenzar a crear tu archivo en formato word, cuando termines de hacer esto, deberías desconectarte del servidor, si es que lo tuvieras que guardar en un servidor compartido.

```
   //Disconnect Auth
    String commandDisconnect = "cmd /c net use \\\\" + ip
            + "\\ipc$ /d";
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandDisconnect);
    //He expects the process to finalize
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandDisconnect);
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        if (exitCode != 0) {
            throw new IOException("Command exited with " + exitCode);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
```

Respuesta en el siguiente [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22338/unknown-user-name-or-bad-password-conectando-a-unidad-de-red-para-operar-archi/23023#23023).

Ojo esto sirve si te vas a conectar a un servidor remoto o local. de las dos maneras es posible, de esa manera tu manejas la ruta del servidor.